# How do I print even numbers using Array

Tags: javascript

I just started with Javascript and was trying to get this script run, which prints even numbers by storing it in an array. But it seems the page keeps on loading with no output.

PS Note : I am new to Java script so try explaining in simple way.

```
var evenArray = [];
var userInput = Number(prompt("Please enter the Number"));
var even = 0;
while(even <= userInput)
{
    evenArray[even] = even + 2;
}
alert(evenArray);
```

Comment: What is the Number function you're using?

Comment: @Script47 It's a way to create a number object in JavaScript.

Comment: Ah, did not know that. Looks like I have some reading to do.

Comment: Use `console.log(evenArray);` instead of alert and view the output using the console in your browser's developer tools. That way you're not dismissing a bunch of alerts to test your code and can quickly see the output.

Comment: In order for the loop to complete, the condition `even <= userInput` has to return `false` at some point. You’re neither changing `even` nor `userInput`. So when will the loop break? Never.

Comment: @Xufox  You are right, i changed my code and it worked

Comment: @MehulChachada Please read [the formatting guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and put backticks around your code in the future (and avoid long code samples in comments, in general).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you have not updated the condition to quit the loop:

```
while(even <= userInput)
```

Try this line:

```
evenArray.push(even);
even += 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually *increment* the `even` variable at some point or it will stay forever at zero and your loop will never exit. In addition, you don't get an even number by adding two to an arbitrary number, you get it by *multiplying* that arbitrary number by two.

That would mean something like:

```
while(even <= userInput) {
    evenArray[even] = even * 2;
    even = even + 1;
}
```

For an input of `7`, that will get you:

```
0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14
```

If instead you need even numbers *up to* the entered number, you modify the loop as follows:

```
while(even <= userInput) {
    evenArray.push(even);
    even = even + 2;
}
```

---

However, once you become comfortable with Javascript, you may want to look into some of the more advanced features, such as the `Array.prototype` methods `.apply()` and `.map()`. Then you can reduce your code to:

```
var sz = Number(prompt("Please enter the Number"));
var evenArray = Array.apply(null,{length: sz / 2 + 1}).map(function(n){
    return (arguments.callee.even = (arguments.callee.even + 2) || 0)
  });
alert(evenArray);
```

The `apply` creates an array of the desired length then uses the `map` function to set all its values to the even numbers.

Probably not as readable as the other solutions but it will be readable to those proficient in the language, and it may even get you a job offer on the spot when your interviewers realise how clever you are :-)

Comment: the problem with multiplying the digit is that if  user enter a number for say 21, the array will print the number up to 48 and  my point is it should print out all the even number till the user has given Input.

Comment: @Mehul, that wasn't clear from your question (I assume you meant `42` rather than `48`) but I've added the code to cater for that as well.

Comment: Yeah i meant 42 on that one, and thanks for letting me know some of this more professional style of coding in Js...Thank you so much for your help i really appreciate it & i would like to know Js in depth so if you could help me with some of the books for reference it would be much helpful..but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to increment the `even` variable and push the number `even` on to the array using `.push()`:

```
var even = 0;

while (even <= userInput) 
{
  evenArray.push( even );
  even = even + 2;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked just fine for me Thanks to Xufox for pointing me my loop mistake and everyone else

```
    var evenArray = [];

    var userInput = Number(prompt("Please enter the Number"));

    for(var even = 0 ; even < userInput; even = even + 2)
    {
        evenArray[even] = even + 2;

    }

    alert(evenArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Even</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
        var label = [];//Declare An Empty Array With A Variable
        for (var even = 2; even < 12; even+=2) { //Initiate For Loop
        label.push(even);//Sends The Values Using For Loop To the Empty Variable 
        }
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = (label);//Print The o/p
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This Code Helps For An Beginner To Understand Whats Happening..Hope It Was Found Helpful. If You Have Any Doubts Regarding push()..Please Visit w3schools.com and search for that in javascript. You Will definitely Understand The Above Program..Cheers!!!! Enjoy Programming